# Change one single iteration on an ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, filter, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have an ng-repeat that iterates through the names of countries in my model. On certain country names I want them abbreviated to reduce the length of the string, for example, I want 'Northern Ireland' to be outputted as 'N. Ireland'.

### JSON Model

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Italy",
  },

  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Northern Ireland",
  },

  {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "Poland",
  }
]
```

I could just change the name in my model, but I'd rather leave that as it is as the I want the raw data to be complete. It is only in this specific instance I want to have it abbreviated.

Should I use an `ng-repeat` filter? If so, how?
If not, any other suggestions?

### HTML

```
<md-grid-tile ng-repeat="nation in nationData">

  <img src="img/{{nation.name}}.png">

  <md-grid-tile-footer>
    <h3>{{nation.name | uppercase}}</h3>
  </md-grid-tile-footer>

</md-grid-tile>
```

Comment: Why not do the modification in your service layer? You could use `map` against the array to apply the abbreviating.

Comment: You could write your own filter and use that.
The filter could check for the string lenght and apply your abbreviating if needed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could create your own filter `abbreviate` that is applied to the name. In this filter you could switch on the country name and return the abbreviated format.

```
app.filter('abbreviate', function() {

    return function(country) {

        switch(country){
            case "Northern Ireland":
                country = "N. Ireland"
                break;
        }

        return country;

    }

});
```

Comment: Thanks - I think this is what I'm after. will accept the answer once I have it working...

Comment: Perfect, just the job. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Like other's said, write your own filter.

```
app.filter('abbreviate', function() {

    return function(country) {
        return country.replace(/^(\S)\S*(\s+\S+)/m, "$1.$2");

    }

});
```

Example:

```js
alert("Northern Ireland".replace(/^(\S)\S*(\s+\S+)/m, "$1.$2"));
alert("South Africa".replace(/^(\S)\S*(\s+\S+)/m, "$1.$2"));
alert("USA".replace(/^(\S)\S*(\s+\S+)/m, "$1.$2"));
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try this. It is simple.

```
<md-grid-tile ng-repeat="nation in nationData">

  <img src="img/{{nation.name}}.png">

  <md-grid-tile-footer>
    <H3 ng-if="nation.name.split(' ').length > 1">{{ nation.name | limitTo:1 | uppercase }}. {{ nation.name.split(' ')[1] }}</H3>
    <H3 ng-if="nation.name.split(' ').length == 1">{{ nation.name }}</H3>
  </md-grid-tile-footer>

</md-grid-tile>
```

Comment: What happens to 'Democratic Republic of Congo' or 'Former Yugoslavian Republic of Macedonia'?

Comment: You can modify based on your output which you want. it's a sample solution.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a custom filter to achieve this, as shown below:

In HTML do this :

```
<h3>{{nation.name | myFormat}}</h3>
```

In your js, define this filer as below:

```
app.filter('myFormat', function() {
    return function(x) {
        x = x.split(" ");
        if(x.length>1){
            x = x[0].split("")[0] + ". " + x[1];
            return x;
        }
        else
            return x[0];
    };
});
```

Please not that as per your req the custom filter can be modified and we can use for loops if you got more than 2 words to be handled as well.

Answer (score 2):

use angular

https://angular-translate.github.io/

then you put all your country names as keys, and you will use the translate filter

```
{{nation.name | translate }}
```

and you can add for example for english language : 
en.json :

```
[
  {
    "Italy": "Italy",
    "Northern Ireland": "N.Ireland",
    "Poland": "Poland",
.....
  }
]
```

Comment: Thanks - that looks really useful. In this case, though I want to learn how to do it 'manually', so to speak.

Comment: yes, in this case you can have these configs outside the code as Internalization options,  and then for different language you could use different templates, it needs a bit more time than a filter, but later it's more clean and maintainable :)

Answer (score 1):

For a simple truncate you can use the `limitTo` filter and it makes sense to keep the model unchanged.

Here a simple example (8 chars):

```
<md-grid-tile ng-repeat="nation in nationData">
  <img src="img/{{nation.name}}.png">

  <md-grid-tile-footer>
    <h3>{{nation.name | limitTo: 8 | uppercase}}</h3>
  </md-grid-tile-footer>

</md-grid-tile>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I don't want to truncate the text, I want a specific filter that turns the first word into a single letter followed by a '.' (e.g. 'N. Ireland')

Comment: @Paulos3000 Sorry I didn't understand this.