# Why does javascript replace method (without regex) doesnt work in angularjs expression to remove &nbsp?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

The SO link [Javascript Regular expression to remove unwanted <br>, &nbsp;](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12838895/javascript-regular-expression-to-remove-unwanted-br-nb) sp tells us to remove an expression using regex.But i want to remove &nb sp; without using regex.Angular expression:

```
{{notification.noti_val)}};Did:{{notification.noti_val.replace(/\&nb sp;/g, ' ')}}
```

.But doesnt delete the `&nb sp;`

Note:did a space between nb and sp cause SO  was parsing it as whitespace so was showing it as whitespace

Comment: If it worked with regular javascript why not use regular JS instead of using the angular library?

Comment: If i go to that link it tells us that parsing html with regex is not a good idea.The link ,which is in that page,is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: *"But i want to remove &nb sp; without using regex"* Why? Calling `replace` with a string instead of a regex in the first argument only replaces the **first** match. In any case, you'll need to give us (much) more to work with, such as a [mcve].

Comment: check the 2nd answer on the link you posted in your question

Comment: @kobe : have used regular js method 'replace';It is not part of angular library

Comment: Why the downvote people?I have my own reasons to not use regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `\s*` instead of a literal space character. `\s` should match any kind of whitespace character. Adding `*` next to `\s` should match any kind of space zero or more times.

```
noti_val.replace(/\&nb\s*sp;/g, ' ')
```

Note that this would replace `&nbsp;` with a space character. If you want to remove then replace it with empty string.

```
noti_val.replace(/\&nb\s*sp;/g, '')
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/nC0sL7/1)

Comment: Avinash will your code work for "&nbsp"?I only gave the space between them cause SO was parsing it as whitespace.Sorry for such a noob in regex

Comment: Ok thanks for your time man but an error is showing.exer Error: Unexpected next character  at columns 31-31 [&] in expression [notification.noti_val.replace(/&nb\s*sp;/g, ' ')].

Comment: is that angular should treat `&` as special char? If yes then escape that.

Comment: Did not work.The error showing now is : `Error: [$parse:lexerr] Lexer Error: Unexpected next character  at columns 31-31 [\] in expression [notification.noti_val.replace(/\&nb\s*sp;/g, ' ')].'The character in the [] is \.SO is not showing it

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/24152/ Please follow this link.And thanks for your time on this

Comment: You got me.But why wasnt it working on the template side?Can you tell.Any ways thanks for the time.and i will accept your answer

Comment: I'm also new to angular. I didn't find an example which uses js in the template side.. Is there any one? Using the above code, you may also define filters. Ex http://stackoverflow.com/a/36452649/3297613